# Drupal: use view output as node content

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I'm writing a Drupal 7 module to display child nodes of a module in the content.
Nodes have a field `parent_nodes` (node reference) where one ore more nodes are selected as parents.

First, I've created a view `projects` with a block view display `subprojects`, displaying nodes of type `project` with a `field_parent_project` contextual filter.

This is my module:

```
<?php

function projects_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['type'] == 'project') {
    if (isset($variables['view_mode']) && $variables['view_mode'] == 'full') {
      _projects_add_subprojects($variables);
    }
  }
}

function _projects_add_subprojects(&$variables) {
  $nid = $variables['nid'];
  $view = views_get_view('projects');
  $preview = $view->preview('subprojects', array($nid));
  $subprojects = array(
      '#title' => t('Subprojects'),
      '#label_display' => 'above',
      '#weight' => 10,
      //'#theme' => 'field',
      '#markup' => $preview,
  );
  if (!isset($variables['content']['subprojects'])) {
    $variables['content']['subprojects'] = array();
  }
  $variables['content']['subprojects'][] = $subprojects;
  dpm($variables['content']);
}
```

This is working, adding the view display output to the node's content.

Only some things aren't working:

- title (label)
- weight do not change display position when rendered with other contents (it's always the first, above body).

If I uncomment the `'#theme' => 'field'` line, title is shown as a label, but nothing is rendered. This is because the field theme is used and I guess it needs `#items` and does not use the `#markup` element.

**I cannot use a children nodes as reference**, but only parent nodes.

**The solution must be independent to theme, so no not answer "change your theme template" or similar**

**How can I show children nodes in node? I'm looking for a way to get something interpretable how a it is was a field**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't already know, the [Viewfield module](http://drupal.org/project/viewfield) allows you to specify a View as a field in your content type.  This may save you some coding but you may not want a whole module to do such a specific task so...

If you want to continue with the custom code which you've written, then you need to re-structure your added content to the correct [render array](http://drupal.org/node/930760) structure that Drupal expects.  Try something like this:

```
  $subprojects_view_output = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $preview,
  );
  $subprojects = array(
      '#theme' => 'field',  
      '#weight' => 10,
      '#title' => t('Subprojects'),
      '#items' => $subprojects_view_output,
  );
```

With the above, the title/label for your field as well as the content of the field (the view itself) should show up.  The code is untested so may not be 100% correct in terms of syntax and all but hopefully gives you a path to a solution.

**EDIT:** I tested the above and it **does not work** because in order to use the existing [theme_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7) function it seems that Drupal expects more information required to render a field like the `#field_name`, `#field_type`, `#entity_type`, etc. as you should see in the warning messages.

Essentially, you are *faking* a field and you will need to provide Drupal with all the info it expects if you want to continue to use the built-in [theme_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7) function, including all the variables as expected in the [preprocess](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7) functions.

Alternatively, you can continue to use your original code and add a `#prefix` to get your title/label to render like this:

```
  $subprojects = array(
      '#weight' => 10,
      '#prefix' => '<div id="subprojects-view">asdf:</div>',
      //'#theme' => 'field',
      '#markup' => $preview,
  );
```

Then style the title/label with CSS accordingly.  I didn't have any problems with the weighting as you described.

Comment: The viewfield module is not what I need, because it let you select a view for each node, but I want to use the view in all nodes of type `project`, not leaving node creator to select the view. I'm trying the second solution.

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato What's not working?  Is it just not showing up?  Are you still missing the title?  Is the order/weight still incorrect?

Comment: No content, no label, no order. If I change `#label` with `#title` it shows the title.

Comment: Thank you! Prefix does the trick! I've added a check to hide the prefix if no results are found.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @nmc, this is my final solution. If no results are found, it does not display the title. The check for results is done by `if (count($view->result) == 0)`. Weight is working.

```
<?php

function projects_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $type = $variables['type'];
  if ($type == 'project' || $type == 'customer') {
    if (isset($variables['view_mode']) && $variables['view_mode'] == 'full') {
      _projects_add_subprojects_markup($variables);
    }
  }
}

function _projects_add_subprojects_markup(&$variables) {
  $nid = $variables['nid'];
  $view = views_get_view('projects');
  $preview = $view->preview('subprojects', array($nid));
  if (count($view->result) == 0) {
    return;
  }
  $variables['content']['subprojects'] = array(
      '#weight' => 10,
      '#prefix' => '<h2>' . t('Subprojects') . '</h2>',
      '#markup' => $preview,
  );
}
```